# looking for help on package for REHL UBI 8/9: saxon

Tags: centos, redhat, ubi

I am migrating our images from centos to RHEL UBI 8/9. it seems that the official UBI repo doesnt offer same packages as centos. when I am doing the yum/microdnf install xxx.
I meet the errors like:
"No package matches 'saxon'"
it seems that saxon is only available in centos 7 than other version.

I also had the issue with expect, mysql and augeas, but they are available in centos stream 9 repo and it seems ok.

could anyone provide a solution for saxon?

Thank you in advance!

searching on https://pkgs.org/search/?q=saxon, it seems that only centos 7 repo has this package.

Comment: Have check how to use `xsltproc`?

Comment: That package seems to be orphaned for certain channels or distributors, https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/fedora-32-missing-saxon-rpm/69833, https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=3781, ...

Comment: will create a RHEL UBI ticket to understand